# WSAStartup() failed, or you have the incorrect version of Winsock installed

Tags: windows-7, utorrent, netsh

I tried Googling around for an answer for this problem but I couldn't find one. So I'm posting here for help. When I try to open uTorrent, I get this error:

`WSAStartup() failed, or you have the incorrect version of Winsock installed.`

This just happened out of the blue. I have no idea what may have caused this. When I try to reset winsock with the 'netsh winsock reset' command in console, I get this error:

`Initialization Function InitHelperDll in NSHHTTP.DLL failed to start with error
code 10107
Access is denied.`

And yes, I have run cmd.exe as administrator.

Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your winsock is corrupted. A solution would be to log into another healthy PC and export the winsock and winsock2 registry keys only from

```
HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services
```

to a flash drive, import them to your local registry, reboot your machine. Else copy the `winsock.dll` files from another healthy PC. The DLL is be located at:

```
c:/WINNT/system32/winsock.dll
```

Replace in your machine and reboot it, your problem will be fixed.

Comment: I don't have winsock file but winsockhc file (Windows 10)